# array.push() is not working for an object in React jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop

trying to pass a const object to an array for my Polygon Dapp. The Array should contain 3 nfts, but when I log it to the console it is empty.

I have logged the consts and they are working perfectly fine. How should I change the loop in order for push() to work?

```
  async function fetchNFTsForContract() {
    const options = {
      chain: "mumbai",
      address: userEthAddress,
      token_address: contractAddress,
    };
    
    const polygonNFTs = await Web3Api.account.getNFTsForContract(options);
    console.log(polygonNFTs); //{total: 3, page: 1, page_size: 100, cursor: null, result: Array(3)}


    let nftArray = [];
      for (let i=0; i< polygonNFTs.length; i++){
    
        const metadataInfo = await fetch(polygonNFTs.result[i].token_uri);
        const metadata = await metadataInfo.json();
        const nft = {"token_id":polygonNFTs.result[i].token_id,"token_uri":polygonNFTs.result[i].token_uri,"contract_type":polygonNFTs.result[i].contract_type,"token_address":polygonNFTs.result[i].token_address,"image":metadata["image"],"name":metadata["name"],"description":metadata["description"]}
        nftArray.push(nft);
        
      };
    console.log(nftArray); // []
    return nftArray;
  };
```

Comment: Please share your complete code

Comment: Where/how do you get `polygonNFTs`? Have you logged `polygonNFTs.length` to make sure it is filled when your function is executed. If it is empty your for loop won't run and skip to the logging of the empty `nftArray`

Comment: I have updated the code with the whole function that gets called @Benjamin

Comment: Have you logged what's happening within the loop to try and narrow down the debugging?

Comment: Your loop looks for `polygonNFTs.length` which doesn't seem to exist.  Try `polygonNFTs.result.length`, or perhaps `polygonNFTs.total`

Comment: @James result.length worked!! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the polygonNFTs const needed to be used as `polygonNFTs.result.length` for the loop condition